# NodeJS - How to parse multipart form data without frameworks?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, forms, http-post

I'm trying to do a basic thing: to send a form using `FormData` API and parse it in NodeJS.

After searching SO for an hour only to find answers using ExpressJS and other frameworks I think it deserves its own question:

I have this HTML:

```
<form action="http://foobar/message" method="POST">
  <label for="message">Message to send:</label>
  <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
  <button>Send message</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://foobar/message');
xhr.send(new FormData(form));
```

In NodeJS I'm doing:

```
var qs = require('querystring');

var requestBody = '';
request.on('data', function (chunk) {
  requestBody += chunk;
});
request.on('end', function () {
  var data = qs.parse(requestBody);
  console.log(data.message);
});
```

But in `data.message` I get the Webkit Boundary thing (from the multipart form data format) instead of the expected message.
Is there another built-in lib to parse multipart post data instead of `querystring`? If not then how to do it manually (high-level, without reading the source code of Express)?

Comment: You should use one of the dozens of packages on npm that do exactly that.

Comment: @SLaks I specifically asked about built-in / manual methods, without using 3rd parties.

Comment: Don't do that.  One of the main points of NodeJS is that the built-in libraries are extremely small, leaving most useful features to other packages.

Comment: There's no easy built in way to do this, you could roll your own, but there's no reason to, parsing the data, getting files etc. can be complicated, the simple [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) has iconv support, parses raw, urlencoded, json, binary and what not, by the time you've written something like that, you've wasted days, maybe weeks, and it's  still not going to be as good the bodyParser you could have installed in five seconds.

Comment: @adeneo I'd rather not use a whole framework like Express. I like to understand what I'm doing and I don't like to depend on 3rd parties for basic stuff. You're right for handling files but in my case It's only a string. Problem is it's not possible to change the enctype of `FormData`.

Comment: Btw `bodyParser` docs say "This does not handle multipart bodies", so it doesn't help even in this simple case.

Comment: Then you'll have to read the [spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7578) and create your own parser based on the rules etc. The different parts are separated by the boundary, so you have to start by recognizing that, then split, and parse each part etc. Good luck.

Comment: There's more than 1 way to understand the frameworks out there, which is a great mindset vs blindly using whats out there.  However, the approach you are suggesting is to reinvent the wheel - which will be error prone and time consuming, but will give you the most knowledge.  Another approach is to read and understand the express source code.  Given that you've already hit a roadblock (had to post to SO) it may the most productive way forward for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `Buffer.from` POST body to `string` then `.split` it by the `boundary` value provided in the `Content-Type:` request header. This gives your `body` parts in an array.

Now process them to determine which is a file and which is a key:val pair. The below code illustrates this.

#### NodeJS / Server Side Example

```
const SERVER = http.createServer(async function(request, response) {
  let statusCode = 200;
  if(request.url === '/app') {
    let contentTypeHeader = request.headers["content-type"];
    let boundary = "--" + contentTypeHeader.split("; ")[1].replace("boundary=","");
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
      let body = [];
      request.on('data', chunk => {
        body.push(chunk)
      });
      request.on('end', async () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        let bodyParts = body.split(boundary);
        let result = [];
        bodyParts.forEach(function(val,index){
          val = val.replace("Content-Disposition: form-data; ","").split(/[\r\n]+/);
          if(isFile(val)){
            result.push(returnFileEntry(val))
          }
          if(isProperty(val)){
            result.push(returnPropertyEntry(val))
          }
        })
        console.log(result)
      });  
      response.end();  
    }
    response.end();
```

Then the processing functions

```
function returnPropertyEntry(arr){
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {return false};
  let propertyName = '';
  let propertyVal = undefined;
  arr.forEach(function(val,index){
    if(val.includes("name=")){
      propertyName = arr[index].split("name=")[1];
      propertyVal = arr[index + 1]
    }
  })
  return [propertyName,propertyVal];
}

function returnFileEntry(arr){
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {return false};
  let fileName = '';
  let file = undefined;
  arr.forEach(function(val,index){
    if(val.includes("filename=")){
      fileName = arr[index].split("filename=")[1];
    }
    if(val.toLowerCase().includes("content-type")){
      file = arr[index + 1];
    }
  })
  return [fileName,file];
}
function isFile(part){
  if(!Array.isArray(part)){return false};
  let filenameFound = false;
  let contentTypeFound = false;
  part.forEach(function(val,index){
    if (val.includes("filename=")){
      filenameFound = true;
    }
    if (val.toLowerCase().includes("content-type")){
      contentTypeFound = true;
    }
  });
  part.forEach(function(val,index){
    if (!val.length){
      part.splice(index,1)
    }
  });
  if(filenameFound && contentTypeFound){
    return part;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
function isProperty(part){
  if(!Array.isArray(part)){return false};
  let propertyNameFound = false;
  let filenameFound = false;
  part.forEach(function(val,index){
    if (val.includes("name=")){
      propertyNameFound = true;
    }
  });
  part.forEach(function(val,index){
    if (val.includes("filename=")){
      filenameFound = true;
    }
  });
  part.forEach(function(val,index){
    if (!val.length){
      part.splice(index,1)
    }
  });
  if(propertyNameFound && !filenameFound){
    return part;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same problem; because the webserver I am using is written in C++ with a Javascript API (which is not the same as Node.js, although standard compliant). So I have to make my own wheel.

Then I come across this npm module [parse-multipart-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-multipart-data). It works, and you can read the source code, it's just one file, and the author explain very clearly what it is, and how to do it.

P.S. as you go higher - you need to go lower. Experience programmer will know what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a function that would replace the `req.formData` method available when using `fetch(req)` when it's not possible to use `fetch`. As in the original question here, I am only interested in returned key:value strings. Unlike here though, I want the result to be in the same format as `.formData` converted with `Object.fromEntries()`. The accepted answer here plus the `getReqData(req)` function at https://www.section.io/engineering-education/a-raw-nodejs-rest-api-without-frameworks-such-as-express/ helped me make this (typescript) function that works for me.

```
function getFormData(request:any) {
  return new Promise<{[key:string]:string}>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const contentTypeHeader = request.headers["content-type"];
      const boundary = "--" + contentTypeHeader.split("; ")[1].replace("boundary=","");
      const body = [] as any;
      request.on('data', (chunk:any) => { body.push(chunk) });
      request.on('end', () => {
        const formDataSubmitted: {[key:string]:string} = {};
        const bodyParts = Buffer.concat(body).toString().split(boundary);
        bodyParts.forEach((val:string) => {
          // After name=.. there are 2 \r\n before the value - that's the only split I want
          // So, the regex below splits at the first occurance of \r\n\r\n, and that's it
          // This way, newlines inside texarea inputs are preserved
          const formDataEntry = returnKeyValObj(
            val.replace("Content-Disposition: form-data; ","").split(/\r\n\r\n(.*)/s)
          );
          if (formDataEntry) Object.assign(formDataSubmitted, formDataEntry);
        })
        if (Object.keys(formDataSubmitted).length) resolve(formDataSubmitted);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  });
}

function returnKeyValObj(arr:Array<string>){
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length < 2) return false;
  let propKey = '';
  const formDataEntries: {[key:string]:string} = {};
  const [pKey, ...pValArray] = arr;
  // pValArray[0] ends with \r\n (2 characters total)
  const propVal = pValArray[0].slice(0,-2)
  // pKey looks like '\r\nname=\"key\"', where \r and \n and \" count as one character each
  // So, need to remove 8 from start of pKey and 1 from end of pKey
  if (pKey && pKey.includes('name=\"')) propKey = pKey.slice(8).slice(0,-1);
  if (propKey) formDataEntries[propKey] = propVal;
  if (Object.keys(formDataEntries).length) return formDataEntries;
  return false;
}
```

So, instead of

```
        const data = await req.formData();
        const dataEntries = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());
```

I can use

```
      const dataEntries = await getFormData(req);
```

And, all the rest of my code stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there i see that you are trying to transfer form data from the frontend to the backend using an http request. Let's do that in an easier and more efficient way: You shall use packetgun-frontend and packetgun-backend npm packages like so (I made those. Don't read their docs it's bad):

In the frontend project folder run the following command

```bash
npm install packetgun-frontend
```

Then write the following in your code (replace ip with the ip of your server as well as port with the port you're listening with)

##### Html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cool form chat website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">
            <h1 id="title">Enter a message:</h1>
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Hello i am a cool dev">
            <button id="send">Send</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<!--The path may be a bit different sometimes-->
<script src="node_modules/packetgun-frontend/packetgun-frontend.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

##### Javascript [app.js]

```js
//Get textbox
var message = document.getElementById("message");
//Get button
var send = document.getElementById("send");
var open = function(){
    packetgun.recommended("127.0.0.1:1234", function (client) {
        send.onclick = function () {
            //On button click send form data...
            client.send({
                "exit_code": 0,
                "data": JSON.stringify({
                    "message": message.value
                })
            })
            //Empty textbox
            message.value = "";
        }
        message.onkeydown = function (event) {
            //If pressed enter key while in the textbox
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                //Click the button
                send.click();
            }
        }
        client.on("serverDisconnect", function(){
            //On client close restart the process
            open();
        })
    })
}
open()
```

In your node.js project folder run the following command

```bash
npm install packetgun-backend
```

Then write the following in your code (replace port with the port you want to use):

```js
//Require packetgun
var packetgun = require("packetgun-backend");

//Init packetgun
packetgun.init()
//Listen with recommended method
packetgun.listen.recommended(port, function(client){
    //When receiving data from client
    client.on("data", function(data){
        //Ignore exit_code and client_exit_code just get client data
        data = data.data;
        //Check if data requires preprocessing
        if (typeof data === "string"){
            try{
                //Preprocess data
                data = JSON.parse(data)
            }
            catch (error){
                //Client data is corrupted
                console.error("Client data is corrupted :(");
                client.close();
            }
        }
        //Close client to mimic an http request (disconnect client)
        client.close();
        //data is the JSON object you sent from the frontend side containing the form data, use that data as you whish
        //For exemple let's stringify and log the data
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    })
})
```

I tested this code, and it works!